# Memory leak in linked list class

Tags: c++

If I run this in visual studio it tells me there are memory leaks, but I don't see anything wrong with my destructor. What did I do wrong? Is it because the memory leak function is being called before the destructor? Am I not supposed to call the memory leak function at the end?

I already posted this on codereview and they said it work fine, but I hadn't included a destructor then. I added one now but I'm not sure if it's actually working.

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <iostream>

using  std::cout;
using  std::cin;
using  std::endl;

struct node {
    int key;
    struct node *next;
};

class linked_list {
    private:
        struct node *head;
        struct node *tail;
    public:
        linked_list() {
            head = nullptr;
            tail = nullptr;
        }

        void create(int key) {
            struct node *temp;
            temp = new struct node;
            temp->key = key;
            temp->next = nullptr;
            head = temp;
            tail = head;
        }


        void insert(int key) {
            if (key < head->key) {
                insert_beginning(key);
            }
            else if ((head->next == nullptr) || (key > tail->key)) {
                insert_end(key);
            }
            else {
                insert_middle(key);
            }
        }

        void insert_beginning(int key) {
            if (head->next == nullptr) {
                tail = head;
            }
            struct node *temp;
            temp = new struct node;
            temp->key = key;
            temp->next = head;
            head = temp;
        }

        void insert_end(int key) {
            struct node *temp;
            temp = new struct node;
            temp->key = key;
            temp->next = nullptr;
            if (head->next == nullptr) {
                head->next = temp;
                tail = temp;
            }
            else {
                tail->next = temp;
            }
            tail = temp;
        }


        void insert_middle(int key) {
            struct node *temp;
            temp = new struct node;
            temp->key = key;

            struct node *current = head;
            struct node *prev = current;

            while (current->key < temp->key) {
                prev = current;
                current = current->next;
            }
            prev->next = temp;
            temp->next = current;
        } 

        void delete_node(int key) {
            if (head == nullptr) {
                cout << "List is empty\n";
                return;
            }

            if (head->key == key) {
                if (head->next == nullptr) {
                    delete(head);
                    head = tail = nullptr;
                }
                struct node *temp = head;
                head = head->next;
                delete(temp);
            }
            else {
                struct node *current = head;
                struct node *prev = current;

                while ((current->key != key) && (current->next != nullptr)) {
                    prev = current;
                    current = current->next;
                }

                if ((current->key != key) && (current->next == nullptr)) {
                    cout << "Key not found\n";
                }
                else if ((current->key == key) && (current->next == nullptr)) {
                    tail = prev;
                    prev->next = nullptr;
                    delete(current);
                }
                else {
                    prev->next = current->next;
                    delete(current);
                }

            }
        }

        void search_node(int key) {
            if (head->key == key || tail->key == key) {
                cout << "Node found\n";
                return;
            }
            struct node *current = head;
            while ((current->key != key) && (current->next != nullptr)) {
                current = current->next;
            }

            if (current->key == key) {
                cout << "Node found\n";
            }
            else {
                cout << "Node not found\n";
            }
        }

        void print_nodes(void) {
            struct node *current = head;
            while (current != nullptr) {
                cout << current->key << '\n';
                current = current->next;
            }
        }

        ~linked_list() {
            struct node *current = head;
            struct node *prev = current;

            while (current->next != nullptr) {
                current = current->next;
                delete(prev);
                prev = current;
            }
            delete(prev);
        }
};


int main(void) {
    linked_list list;

    list.create(0);

    for (int i = 1; i < 20; ++i) {
        list.insert(i);
    }

    list.search_node(5);
    list.search_node(0);
    list.search_node(-1);

    list.delete_node(19);
    list.delete_node(0);

    list.print_nodes();

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}
```

Comment: Memory leaks can happen outside of the destructor. There are several places in your code where you call `new` without ever `delete`ing that variable later.

Comment: Why are you even using C++ with raw pointers?

Comment: @ShadowMitia Everytime I call `new` it's to add something to the list, the destructor eventually deletes the entire list. I don't think I'm allocating something outside the list?

Comment: @M.Shaw I don't know what you mean by that, what's the alternative to creating a linked list?

Comment: @MichaelX a lot of the uses for raw pointers in C++11 and later can be replaced with smart pointers (unique_ptr and shared_ptr). Unfortunately a linked list is one of those things that are still best done with raw pointers (because using unique_ptr can lead to a stack overflow upon destruction)

Comment: @MichaelX Yeah my bad, I should've taken more time on your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();`, you have not yet destructed your `list` object.

UPDATE

Adding a set of braces so as to destruct `list` before doing the memory leak diagnostic.

```
int main(void) {
  {
    linked_list list;

    list.create(0);

    for (int i = 1; i < 20; ++i) {
        list.insert(i);
    }

    list.search_node(5);
    list.search_node(0);
    list.search_node(-1);

    list.delete_node(19);
    list.delete_node(0);

    list.print_nodes();
  }
  _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I figured that's what's happening. How am I supposed to fix it? Can I stop it from automatically calling the destructor so I can manually call it before `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();`?

Comment: The braces fixed this, thanks. But can you elaborate why? What are the rules for calling the destructor? 

Nevermind, it went out of scope so it got destructed.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do a leak check as late as possible with MSVC is to enable the automatic dump functionality, with the following code:
 _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_REPORT_FLAG)|_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);

This will do a leak check after main/WinMain has returned and global object destructors have run. And if you've ever seen an MFC dump report that is how it is enabled.